# IPhone app xcode, trying to hide text input by clicking on the background?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uicontrol, keypad, resignfirstresponder

I'm following an example in Beginning Iphone Development 4 for basic user interaction.

I'm using xcode 4.02 with sdk 4.3

I have a basic viewcontroller.xib with two textbox's, one for numeric values and another for text. Once I'm finished editing either of the text fields I wish to tap the background and have the keypad disappear.

The books says to change the container UIView object to a UIControl and then add an action onto the UIControl event Touch Down. Then create a method to resign the first responder of each of the textbox's and link this to the touch down event. I've done this. Here is my code, is there anything I've missed? At the moment nothing happens.

[image]
Thanks

```
@interface ControlFunViewController : UIViewController {
    UITextField *nameField;
    UITextField *numberField;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *numberField;

- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender;
```

Implementation:

```
#import "ControlFunViewController.h"

@implementation ControlFunViewController

@synthesize nameField;
@synthesize numberField;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [nameField release];
    [numberField release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender {
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}
- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender {
    [nameField resignFirstResponder];
    [numberField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, I didn't link up the outlets for the text boxes so the controller didn't no they existed. School boy error.

http://www.iphonedevbook.com/forum/chapter-4-more-user-interface-fun/4145-backgroundtap.html

Answer (score 2):

This link will help you. It addresses hiding the keyboard in several different ways. http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-uitextfield-tutorial-handling-keyboard-interactions/

I actually had the same exact problem in the same book earlier this year. I realized that I wasn't reading carefully and missed just one small instruction so I re-read it carefully and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'm still bemused, I've re-read the example in the book and also the link you provided. I cant see whats I'm missing?

Comment: The `textFieldDoneEditing` and `BackgroundTap` methods in that blog posting are great. The rest of the code is broken, however (missing import statements and blog HTML mixed in with source code listing) so ignore everything in the second half of the post (from "Text Field Hiding behind keypad" onward).

Answer (score 1):

Change the UIView to UIControl from the identify tab of inspector ->class identity section. 
add this

```
-(IBACTION)tabBackground: (id) sender;
```

to your .h file

add this to your .m file

```
-(IBACTION) tabBackgroup: (id)sender {
[nameField resignFirstRespnder];
[numberField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

connect your tabBackgroupnd from the inspector, action receive section to the UIVIEW (which is an UIControl now) and your good to go. let me know if you have anyproblem